# CSS+ HTML + JAVA - Add link to language option / combo box

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

good day. See the code below. I have 4 languages. I want to add a link to each languages, so as to access a new page every time I choose the language from the combo. How can I do this?

```
<!-- FLAGS -->
<div class="language-picker js-language-picker" data-trigger-class="btn btn--subtle js-tab-focus">
  <form action="" class="language-picker__form">
    <label for="language-picker-select">Select your language </label>

    <select name="language-picker-select" id="language-picker-select">
      <option lang="de" value="deutsch">Deutsch</option>
      <option lang="en" value="english" selected>English</option>
      <option lang="fr" value="francais">Français</option>
      <option lang="it" value="italiano">Italiano</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- FLAGS -->
```

For example, I change this line, add a link. But is not working.

```
<option lang="de" value="deutsch" <a href="https://google.com">Deutsch</a> </option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with onchange event that will be trigred with each change

```
<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="">Pick one:</option>
    <option value="/de">Deutsch</option>
    <option value="/fr">Français</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, Karim . And if I want to add an icon with flag to each language, how can I do that? Maybe you can UPDATE an answer also with this new option.